# Is there a way to trace click once application

Tags: clickonce

I am trying to build a WPF click once application and going to host it on a server, then will install it to 10 client. May I know is there any way to trace the client version from server level? Example, today I had updated server version to 1.15, but i am not able to know when or had the client update to latest version 1.15.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in way in ClickOnce, however you can either monitor downloads of you application manifest file (.application) on your web server or check the [`ApplicationDeployment.IsFirstRun`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.deployment.application.applicationdeployment.isfirstrun) ("The value of this property is reset whenever the user upgrades from one version to the next.") property every time your application launches and call an API you would setup on your server that logs the installation.

If you go with that, make sure that you handle all exception in the logging call and that the execution keeps going even if the logging fails.

You could also switch to manual updating using the methods on the [`ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.deployment.application.applicationdeployment?view=netframework-4.7.2) object to completely decide how the update process is handled but it will add a layer of complexity to you application.